# Jenkinsfile pipeline stdout variable as integer

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I frequently use the `VAR = sh(returnStdout: true, script './script.sh').trim()` syntax in a declarative `Jenkinsfile` to set a variable in which I will refer to later in the pipeline. One thing I have not been able to figure out, is how can I get this to convert to an integer if I want to write a greater than/less than conditional?

I've tried

```
VAR = sh(returnStdout: true, script './script.sh').trim().toInteger()
if (VAR > 1) {
  // do something
}
```

And this does not work. How come? What is the correct way to do this? I've also tried by separating them and not pipeing it right after the `.trim()`

```
VAR = sh(returnStdout: true, script './script.sh').trim()
VAR.toInteger()
if (VAR > 1) {
  // do something
}
```

And this doesn't work either. How can I achieve making the `sh` output an integer that can be used in a greater than conditional statement?

Comment: Your first option actually works for me.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe a particular setting or configuration or plugin? Not sure if it matters but I'm using 2.249.1 version of Jenkins and it's in a declarative pipeline, however this does not work for me in the script console either.